# JAX-RS writer interceptor works for every response even with NameBinding

Tags: jax-rs, interceptor, name-binding

I need to intercept a response from the server that was generated for a specific API call and change it. 

 I used the JAX-RS ***'WriterInterceptor'*** for this and I have created a NameBinding as well. 
 But the server is intercepting every response out from the server. What am I doing wrong here?

Shown below is the code I have tried. Why is the name binding does not work? (I have verified that when calling other API resources the particular method that I have use name binding is not called.)

***Name Binding***.

```
package com.example.common.cm.endpoint;


@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@NameBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface JSONtoJWT {}
```

***The Interceptor***.

```
package com.example.common.cm.endpoint;


@Provider
@JSONtoJWT
public class TestInterceptor implements WriterInterceptor {

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(TestInterceptor.class);

    @Override
    public void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext writerInterceptorContext) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

        log.info("interceptor invoked");

        OutputStream outputStream = writerInterceptorContext.getOutputStream();

        outputStream.write(("{\"message\": \"Message added in the writer interceptor in the server side\"}").getBytes());

        writerInterceptorContext.setOutputStream(outputStream);
        writerInterceptorContext.proceed();

        log.info("Proceeded");

    }
}
```

***API Resource***.

```
package com.example.cm.endpoint.u3.acc;

@Path("/u3/some-validation")
@Consumes({ "application/json; charset=utf-8" })
@Produces({ "application/json; charset=utf-8" })
public class SomeValidationApi  {

 @POST
    @Path("/")
    @JSONtoJWT
    @Consumes({ "application/json; charset=utf-8" })
    @Produces({ "application/json; charset=utf-8" })
    public Response someValidationPost(@ApiParam(value = "validations post" ,required=true ) SomeValidationRequestDTO someValidationConsent)
    {
        return delegate.someValidationPost(someValidationConsent);
    }
}
```

***beans.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>
    <context:property-placeholder/>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PreferencesPlaceholderConfigurer"/>

<jaxrs:server id="services" address="/">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>

     ***Some other beans here***

            <bean class="com.example.cm.endpoint.u3.acc.SomeValidationApi/>
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>

        <jaxrs:providers>
            <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider"/>
            <bean class="com.example.common.cm.endpoint.TestInterceptor"/>
        </jaxrs:providers>
    </jaxrs:server>
</beans>
```

When I use the above every response from the server is intercepted and the message is added. But I want only the particular resource to invoke the Interceptor.

Also, ***Other than JAX-RS interceptor with writerInterceptor, are there any other good alternative to achieve this?***